# How to extract specific values after a specific string and store it to different variables?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, variable

I am very new to Linux. I need to parse one summary file which generates at the end of our automation. Below is that summary file:

```
Total_Test_Cases_Count:25
Total_Pass:24
Total_Fail:1
Execution_Duration:5m 7sec
Pass_Percentage:96.11%
Failure_Percentage:3.89%
```

I want these values separately in variables so that I can pass it to some other function.

My expected  Output:

```
Total_Test_Cases_Count(as a variable) with value 25.
Total_Pass(as a variable) with value 24.
```

Similarly for others.

What I tried till now:

```
awk "NR==1" summary.txt
```

which gives

```
TotalCount:25
```

Answer (score 2):

It is best to do this with an associative array. e.g.

```
declare -A array

while IFS=: read key val; do
  array["$key"]="$val"
done < input.txt

for key in Total_Test_Cases_Count Total_Pass; do
  printf '%s=%s\n' "$key" "${array[$key]}"
done
```

Output:

```
Total_Test_Cases_Count=25
Total_Pass=24
```

---

This will fail if any of the values contain the field separator (a colon, `:`).  In that case, you first need to change the field separator in the input to something that isn't in either of the fields.  A tab is often a good choice.  For example:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read key val; do
  array["$key"]="$val"
done < <(sed -e 's/:/\t/1' input.txt)
```

IFS is set to use a tab as the delimiter, and the `sed` command changes the first (and only the first) colon character to a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk and eval:

```
eval "$(awk -F: '{ print $1 "='\''" $2 "'\''" }' tmp)"
```

The command inside `$()` parses summary.txt. With the `-F` option we tell awk to use `:` as field delimiter. It formats each line like this:

```
Total_Pass='24'
```

I had to [escape the single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9899001); that is why the code looks so ugly.

eval is used to execute the formatted text just as you had written that in your script. As you can guess this is **dangerous** if you don’t have full control over your input data. See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220) Maybe someone can point out a safer way to do this.

You then can use your new variables like that:

```
printf "Total_Pass with value %s\n" "$Total_Pass"
```